Managing Time-to-Live (TTL) for Alerts in Prometheus
We're collecting EUR/USD prices every minute on Prometheus and setting up various alerts, such as percentage changes over the last 10 minutes and the last hour.
The data flow works seamlessly; however, I am unable to set a time-to-live (TTL) on the alerts. For instance, an alert triggered a month ago remains active in Prometheus. I want to set a TTL on alerts, similar to Redis keys, so they are automatically deleted after the TTL expires. As far as I can tell, this isn't possible with Prometheus, resulting in many outdated alerts still being active.
Is Prometheus the right tool for this scenario?
Can I delete alerts programmatically, assuming there is no TTL feature?

You can't delete Alerts but you can Silence them (see Alertmanager APIs). I assume (!?) that your alerts are labeled so that the underlying expr remains valid (if it didn't the alert would disappear) and they're being overwritten.
